# Windows Server 2012 routing and remote access instalation failed

Tags: routes, installation, roles, windows-server-2012

I installed windows server 2012 and one role, Routing and Remote Access.
There are two big problems.

1) This role, it wants DirrectAccess to be enable, but I couldn't find where is anything as administration of DirrectAccess.

2) Before I want to complete wizard "Enable and configure Routing and Remote Access" in administration, it everytime fail with error 80040154 Class not registered.

On the server is just this role. Anything was there before. It was new instalation.

Please. Tell me how can I fix this errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy it was Remote Access role, which I had to install. The instalation pack includes DirrectAccess, VPN, Routing and other. In Server managmant, there was only the console, but the core of it was installed after I installed the role.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the NPS Role first:

Start the Server Manager -> Add Roles -> Network Protection Services